# Gatsby MDX and root relative paths

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image, gatsby-remark-image

I have two occasions in MDX files, where I would like to use root relative instead of relative paths. MDX pages are deeply nested. So I end up in many `../../..`

Folder-examples are:

```
/content/products/
/content/products/brands/some-brand/index.mdx
/content/products/brands/some-brand/some-feature/first-product.mdx
/content/images/brand-images/some-brand.png
/content/images/brand-images/other-brand.png
/src/components/products/
```

## Frontmatter image paths

I followed [this example](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/working-with-images-in-markdown/#configuring-for-images-and-posts-in-different-directories).

```
---
title: Some title
brand-image: ../../../images/brand-images/some-brand.png
---
```

## Components

```
import Products from '../../../../src/components/products';
```

## Is something like this possible?

```
---
title: Some title
brand-image: ${PROJECT_ROOT}/content/images/brand-images/some-brand.png
---

import Products from '${PROJECT_ROOT}/src/components/products';

Hi, I'm a page with many products. It's just to show, how I use the MDX pages.

<Products pkey="some-brand" tags={/.*Corp.*Gov.*/}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saw an upvote and came over this old question. So, here is the solution.

**Frontmatter Image Paths and Components**

The https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-remark-normalize-paths/ resolves this problem.

**Components only**

With [shortcodes](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#shortcodes) we can completely eliminate the need of explicit component
imports in MDX files.

Let's say, you have a template "around" your MDX content.

```
...
<MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer>
...
```

Let's say, you use a custom component `<BlueBox />` in your MDX content files. Import this component in the template and wrap `<MDXRenderer>` with `<MDXProvider>`

```
...
import BlueBox from "../components/mdx/blue-box"
import AnotherComponent from "../components/mdx/another-component"
...
<MDXProvider components={{BlueBox, AnotherComponent}}><MDXRenderer>{body}</MDXRenderer></MDXProvider>
...
```